# Missing firebase_core/FirebaseCorePlugin.h

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I get the following error when it try to run flutter:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              2.2s
                                                                                                                                                                                                           ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           1.8s                                                                                             
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.3s
Xcode build done.                                           10.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/me/Downloads/myapp2/my_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'firebase_core/FirebaseCorePlugin.h' file not found
    #import <firebase_core/FirebaseCorePlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XR.
```

`flutter doctor` says everything is correct, I've ran `flutter packages get`, changed the channel to dev and I've tried various iterations of  deleting the `podspec.lock` and the `Podfile.lock`, but no luck. Although I can't see this file anywhere in my app, I can see it in the firebase_core git repo. Is there somewhere I can manually place it to be found?

Answer (score 0):

How is solved this was:

1. reinstalled Flutter to a new directory
2. Changed to the beta release `flutter channel beta`
3. Created a new app
4. In my pubspec.yaml file, set the link to the *latest* firebase_core version available in git (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md).

> ```
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>   firebase_core: ^0.3.1  # add dependency for Firebase Core
> ```

5. Ran `flutter packages get`
6. In the ios folder, ran `pod install`